# Horizontal sub menu

Tags: html, css, menu, submenu

I'd like to create horizontal submenu. Hovewer now I created only dopdown submenu. I have following css and html code, please see demo:

Can you help me improve my code? Thank you.

**HTML**

```
<ul id="menu-main-menu" class="top_big_menu"><li id="menu-item-4192" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-home menu-item-4192"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-4159" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-4159"><a href="#">Football</a><ul>
        <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Interviews</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Comments</a></li>
        </ul></li>
<li id="menu-item-4160" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-4160"><a href="#">Football 2</a><ul>
        <li><a href="#">News 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Interviews 2</a></li>
        </ul></li>
<li id="menu-item-4161" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category current-menu-item menu-item-4161"><a href="#">Football 3</a><ul>
        <li><a href="http://www.example.com/child1.com">News 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.example.com/child2.com">Interviews 3</a></li>
        </ul></li>
<li id="menu-item-4190" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4190"><a href="#">Menu 4</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-4189" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4189"><a href="#">Menu 5</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.top_big_menu li{
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
    position: relative;
    bottom: -10px;
    float: left;
    margin-left:1px;
}

.top_big_menu li a{
    font-family: 'Calibri',sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #212121;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: block;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    line-height: 50px;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s;
    transition: all 0.2s;
}

.top_big_menu li a:hover{
    background-color: #E31E24;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.top_big_menu  .current-menu-item a, .top_big_menu .current_page_item a{
    background-color: #E31E24;
    color: #fff;
}

.top_big_menu li ul{
display: none;
position:absolute;
z-index:2;
padding-bottom:13px;
}

.top_big_menu li:hover ul{ display:inline;
color:white;
background:#E31E24;
height:auto; 
border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;  }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mart01/8vbnhxx0/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Horizontal css menu question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5318393/horizontal-css-menu-question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#menu-main-menu{
position: relative;
}
```

Apply the above code instead of applying `position:relative` to `.top_big_menu li{}` Check this [link](https://jsfiddle.net/praveen_04/s8kh72en/4/).

Comment: hey add the above style in your stysheet and remove `position:relative` from `.top_big_menu li{}`

Comment: Thank you,you helped me a lot.

Answer (score -2):

Example [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1cb1v5nn/) vertical and horizontal menus. In your example, you need to use the direct style inheritance and use: hover from there and not from links [on this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8vbnhxx0/1/).

```css
.menu {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
}

.sub-menu {
  display: none;
  /* position: absolute; */
  top: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.sub-menu > li {
  position: relative;
}

.sub-menu > li > a {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

.menu > li {
  /* position: relative; */
  padding: 5px;
}

.menu li:hover > .sub-menu {
  display: block;
}

.menu > li > a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background-color: tomato;
}

.sub-menu .sub-menu {
  padding-left: 20px;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  min-width: 120px;
}

.menu-inline > li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.menu-inline .sub-menu {
  position: absolute;
}

.menu-inline .sub-menu .sub-menu {
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li>
    <a href="#">menu-link</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li>
        <a href="#">sub-menu-link</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li>
            <a href="#">sub-menu-link</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
              <li><a href="#">sub-menu-link</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">sub-menu-link</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">sub-menu-link</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">sub-menu-link</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">sub-menu-link</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">sub-menu-link</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">sub-menu-link</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">sub-menu-link</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">sub-menu-link</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">menu-link</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li><a href="#">sub-menu-link</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">sub-menu-link</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">sub-menu-link</a>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">menu-link</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li><a href="#">sub-menu-link</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">sub-menu-link</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">sub-menu-link</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">sub-menu-link</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">menu-link</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li><a href="#">sub-menu-link</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">sub-menu-link</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">sub-menu-link</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">sub-menu-link</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>





<ul class="menu menu-inline">
  <li>
    <a href="#">menu-link</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li>
        <a href="#">sub-menu-link</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li><a href="#">sub-menu-link</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">sub-menu-link</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
              <li><a href="#">sub-menu-link</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">sub-menu-link</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">sub-menu-link</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">sub-menu-link</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>

          <li><a href="#">sub-menu-link</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">sub-menu-link</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">sub-menu-link</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">sub-menu-link</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">menu-link</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li><a href="#">sub-menu-link</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">sub-menu-link</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">sub-menu-link</a>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">menu-link</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li><a href="#">sub-menu-link</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">sub-menu-link</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">sub-menu-link</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">sub-menu-link</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">menu-link</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li><a href="#">sub-menu-link</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">sub-menu-link</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">sub-menu-link</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">sub-menu-link</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```